# Ruby on rails: working out and storing an average from data within another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an educations model which belongs to a university model and university has many educations. I have a rating column which is an integer in the education table but in the university table this is a decimal. What I would like to do is each time an education is created or updated I would like the average of that specific university to be updated and stored in the university table. My solution below is not working, so could someone please point me in the right direction? Here is wat I have in the university model.

## method to update the average rating. This method will be called each time an education record is added or updated

```
def updateDisabilityDeptRating
  @value = 0.00
  self.educations.disabilityDeptRating.each do |rating|
    @value = @value + rating.value
  end

  @total = self..educations.disabilityDeptRating.size
  update_attributes(disabilityDeptRating: @value.to_f / @total.to_f)
end
```

educations model:

```
after_create :updateUniversityRatings
after_update :updateUniversityRatings

# method to run the update method in the university model 
def updateUniversityRatings
  university.updateDisabilityDeptRating
end
```

Comment: please format your code accordingly

Comment: My apologies. I am blind and using a screen reader, which is not able to sufficiently format on this website.

Comment: just a note on ruby coding conventions, snake case is never used - method, instance and variable names are always lower_case_with_underscores and class names are Pascal case and constants are ALL_CAPS

Comment: Your code looks correct as far as I can tell, however `update_attributes` might be returning false due to validation errors?  try `update_attribute(:disabilityDeptRating, @value.to_f / @total.to_f)` instead

Comment: I'm getting this error for the code in the university model. undefined method `disabilityDeptRating' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Education:0x000000067cb360>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with

```
undefined method `disabilityDeptRating' for # ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_Collect‌​ionProxy_Education:0x000000067cb360>
```

can be fixed with this change:

```
self.educations.each do |education|
  @value = @value + education.disabilityDeptRating
end
```

rails / ruby allow us to clean this up a bit if desired

```
value = self.educations.sum(&:disabilityDeptRating)
```

---

a couple of other pointers:

- in the `updateDisabilityDeptRating` method `@value` and `@total` are only used in that method so you can drop the `@` which is turning them into instance/member variables which is not needed in this case.
- instead of using `after_create` and `after_update` you can use `after_save`